# Тема курсового по базам данных

Tags: c++, sql, база-данных

Помогите выбрать тему для курсового проекта по базам данных. Например, какую-нибудь игру по сети, т.к. приложение должно быть клиент-серверным. Функционал базы данных не должен ограничиваться вводом/редактированием/удалением/сортировкой/поиском информации, а что-нибудь еще "эдакое". Программы типа "Склад того-то и того-то" не подходят.)

Comment: вам подойдет любая примитивная игра с авторизацией пользователей и хранением результатов на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Как вариант - сделайте клиент-серверное приложение для *трекинга* объектов.

> - Сервер содержит большую базу изображений, клиент отправляет произвольную картинку и от сервера приходят все изображения, где так или иначе присутствует картинка от клиента.
> - Можно, например, учитывать только простые деформации, а можно делать что-нибудь крутое типа `SIFT / SURF / ORB`.

- Понятно, что если изображения являются фотографиями, то такое приложение **внезапно** становится полезным и интересным.

Comment: Спасибо, тема действительно интересная. Но боюсь, за три месяца не справлюсь. Уж больно много нового всего изучить надо(

Answer (score 1):

- Много пользователей он-лайн рисуют огромное дерево ассоциаций/UML диаграмму/блок-схему/граф. Диаграмма хранится на сервере. Есть история правок,возможность откатов, модерация. К каждому узлу графа кроме названия можно приделать гиперссылку. Бесполезная штуковина конечно, но можно попробовать и достаточно легко реализуется.
- Он-лайн комната для игры в настольные игры вроде шашек/шахмат.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что первая штука легко реализуется :)

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте систему рейтингов для внутреннего использования в компании.
Со всякими примочками, типа, фиксированного количества голосов в день, фиксированное количество голосований за любого пользователя в день, сделайте возможность помимо изменения кармы пользователя, так-же, оставлять комментарии к соответствующему действию. Реализуйте возможность применять к пользователям различного рода статусы. Например, у пользователя со статусом "Доктор зло" при каждом последующем отрицательном голосе сила голоса увеличивается на 0.1 к примеру, а "богу" при "минусовании" кармы эти баллы автоматически начисляются в положительные. При статусе "Вампир", если тебе "минуснули" в карму, то у минусующего автоматически списывается положительный балл, а у тебя минусовой балл не засчитывается. Как то так.

Я сделал подобное для шуточного использования внутри компании, осталось только статусы сделать. Довольно весело получается :]